# New to Drupal 8 - Using PHP script in page content?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have a PHP script that connects to the MySQL database and pulls the information from it and loads it into a searchable table.  If I load localhost/testphp.php

everything works fine and its all great, but I am trying to get that page added into Drupal 8, However, but I am not sure the best way to go about it.
As when you create a page within Drupal it does not seem to run PHP code.

Below is basically what I've got written.

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:20%;">Drawing ID</th>
    <th style="width:25%;">Sheet Number</th>
    <th style="width:25%;">Revision</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">First Title Line</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Second Title Line</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Third Title Line</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Fourth Title Line</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">Notes</th>
    </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
<?php

require '../scripts/connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM drawing_data";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die("Bad Query: $sql");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo"<tr><td>{$row['First Part']} / {$row['Second Part']} / {$row['Third Part']} / {$row['Fourth Part']} </td><td>{$row['Sheet Number']}</td><td>{$row['Revision']}</td><td>{$row['First Title Line']}</td><td>{$row['Second Title Line']}</td><td>{$row['Third Title Line']}</td><td>{$row['Fourth Title Line']}</td><td>{$row['Notes']}</td><tr>";
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I am new to using Durpal and its been a long time since I've done any web dev type stuff. So there is probably a better way around it, but I feel like I am not smart enough to work it out by myself.

Comment: Drupal uses the MVC pattern, this means the data in the view has to be passed down from the controller. Could you show the controller that displays the view?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is there anything in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Search on how to create custom page in Drupal 8. There are a lot of tutorials on that subject on net. I.e.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-page

.. or ..

https://www.anubavam.com/blogs/how-to-develop-custom-page-on-drupal-8

Or find some other, maybe video tutorial.

Basically you have to define a route and then controller that will be called for that route. Also would be good to use drupal's theming system and to put html in twig templates.